# HP Windows 7 Upgrade - Can I use it on a non HP computer?

Tags: windows-7, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7 and Vista Activation FAQ: how do language, version, 64-bit or 32-bit, and source affect ability to install and transfer Windows licenses?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/windows-7-and-vista-activation-faq-how-do-language-version-64-bit-or-32-bit-a)

I bought a HP laptop with Vista Home Premium on it.  I was entitled to the Windows 7 upgrade so I sent away for it.  I sold my HP laptop and I just received the Windows 7 Upgrade DVD from HP.  Can I use the Windows 7 Upgrade DVD (or key that came with it) to install Windows 7 on a NON HP computer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible/probable that you CAN, but it is also likely a violation of the OEM license agreement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Now it is a OEM copy. BUT it should work just fine. yet IF you only have a upgrade key then you might have a problem. i would look up something called windows 7 loader. it might help your situation. by the way i have a hp oem windows 7 64 installed on my dell. so have fun!!